# Reload, Hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, funções

Olá, gostaria de saber como faço para que apareça a mensagem do **window.onbeforeunload** sem a opção de **Impedir que esta página crie caixas de diálogo adicionais**, para todas as formas de sair da página com por exempo, fechar o navegador, F5, cliques em hyperlinks, ETC.

Aguardo uma resposta, agradeço desde já, abraços!

Comment: Não sei se é possível isso.. pois essa mensagem é um modo de segurança do chrome para proteger o usuário de incômodos, mas a pergunta é boa

Comment: Obrigado Silvio, vamos ver se alguém pode nos ajudar então :)